# Scaling Matrix in R so that X %*% t(X) Only has Diagonal Elements of One

Tags: r, matrix

So I have an `n x p` matrix `X`, and I want to scale this matrix so that `X` times its transpose has diagonal elements one only. That is, I want

```r
diag(X %*% t(X)) # n x p matrix X
```

to equal

```r
rep(1,n)
```

I know it can be done with the help of the `scale` function in R, but not sure about the specifics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have each row of `X` divided by the square root of its sum of squares.

```r
set.seed(123)
X <- matrix(rnorm(15), 3, 5)

divisor <- sqrt(rowSums(X^2))
Y <- X / divisor

Y %*% t(Y)
#            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
# [1,]  1.0000000 -0.5620878 -0.6140127
# [2,] -0.5620878  1.0000000  0.2485122
# [3,] -0.6140127  0.2485122  1.0000000
```